# python syntax error with simple conditional statement

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

Here is the code.  Not sure why I'm getting a syntax error at the If statement for Endtime > Maxtime.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jeff

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import time

Zone = False
MaxTime = 5.0
StartTime = time.time()

for x in range(0,10):
    time.sleep(1)
    Now = time.time()
    EndTime = StartTime - Now
    If (EndTime > MaxTime):
        print "Seconds: %f" % EndTime

Print "Finishing up"
Now = time.time()
EndTime = StartTime - Now
print "Seconds: %f" % EndTime
```

Comment: Capitalization matters.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `If` to `if` and `Print` to `print`. Python is case sensitive.